# Is there a way to define NamedQueries outside of entity?

Tags: configuration, jpa

I use Netbeans as IDE and use the wizards to generate Entities. If I want to define custom NamedQueries (not the ones auto generated) how can I define those outside of the entity so I don't lose them if I have to recreate the entity using the wizard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the custom named queries instead like:

```
        <persistence-unit>
         ...
        <named-query name="xxxxxx">
        <query>
        <![CDATA[
        SELECT x FROM XXXXXXXX x
        ]]>
        </query>
        </named-query>
        </persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Found the answer myself after some more investigation.